# Given a stock of integers 0-9, what is the last number I can write before I run out of some integer?

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers, dynamic-programming

As the title says, given a stock of integers 0-9, what is the last number I can write before I run out of some integer?

So if I'm given a stock of, say 10 for every number from 0 to 9, what is the last number I can write before I run out of some number. For example, with a stock of 2 I can write numbers 1 ... 10:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

at this point my stock for ones is 0, and I cannot write 11.
Also note that if I was given a stock of 3, I could still write only numbers 1 ... 10, because 11 would cost me 2 ones, which would leave my stock for ones at -1.

What I have come up so far:

```
public class Numbers {

public static int numbers(int stock) {
    int[] t = new int[10];
    for (int k = 1; ; k++) {

        int x = k;
        while (x > 0) {

            if (t[x % 10] == stock) return k-1;
            t[x % 10]++;
            x /= 10;

        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(numbers(4));

}

}
```

With this I can get the correct answer for fairly big stock sizes. With a stock size of 10^6 the code completes in ~2 seconds, and with a stock of 10^7 numbers it takes a whole 27 seconds. This is not good enough, since I'm looking for a solution that can handle stock sizes of as big as 10^16, so I probably need a O(log(n)) solution.

This is a homework like assignment, so I didn't come here without wrestling with this pickle for quite some time. I have failed to come up with anything similiar by googling, and wolfram alpha doesn't recognize any kind of pattern this gives.

What I have concluded so far is that ones will allways run out first. I have no proof, but it is so.

Can anyone come up with any piece of advice? Thanks a lot.

---

### EDIT:

I have come up with and implemented an efficient way of finding the cost of numbers 1...n thanks to btilly's pointers (see his post and comments below. also marked as a solution). I will elaborate this further after I have implemented the binary search for finding the last number you can write with the given stock later today.

---

### EDIT 2: The Solution

I had completely forgotten about this post, so my apologies for not editing in my solution earlier. I won't copy the actual implementation, though.

My code for finding the cost of a number does the following:

First, let us choose a number, e.g. 9999. Now we will get the cost by summing the cost of each tens of digits like so:

```
9 9 9 9
^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^ roof(9999 / 10^1) * 10^0 = 1000
^ ^ roof(9999 / 10^2) * 10^1 = 1000
^ roof(9999 / 10^3) * 10^2 = 1000
roof(9999 / 10^4) * 10^3 = 1000
```

Thus the cost for 9999 is 4000.

the same for 256:

```
2 5 6
^ ^ ^
^ ^ roof(256 / 10^1) * 10^0 = 26
^ roof(256 / 10^2) * 10^1 = 30
roof(256 / 10^3) * 10^2 = 100
```

Thus the cost for 256 is 156.

Implementing with this idea would make the program work only with numbers that have no digits 1 or 0, which is why further logic is needed. Let's call the method explained above ***C(n, d)***, where ***n*** is the number for which we are getting the cost for, and ***d*** is the **d**'th digit from ***n*** that we are currently working with. Let's also define a method ***D(n, d)*** that will return the **d**'th digit from ***n***. Then we will apply the following logic:

```
sum = C(n, d)

if D(n, d) is 1:
    for each k < d, k >= 0 :
        sum -= ( 9 - D(n, k) ) * 10^(k-1);

else if D(n, d) is 0:
    sum -= 10^(d-1)
```

With this the program will calculate the correct cost for a number efficiently. After this we simply apply a binary search for finding the number with the correct cost.

Comment: You'd definitely run out of 1s first. Numbers in a range tend to start with 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1.  Write an efficient function to calculate how much stock needs to be used to write all of the numbers up to `N`.  (Hint: calculate everything that was used to write out the numbers in the last digit with a formula, and then use recursion to calculate everything that was used in the other digits.)

Step 2.  Do a binary search to find the last number you can write with your amount of stock.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you clarify that hint-bit? I'm afraid it escaped by understanding.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja I believe this to be a homework problem, and so wanted to leave you with something to do.  If you can't make sense of the hint, just focus on estimating how to quickly calculate how much stock was used up to `N`.  Even if you don't find the recursive solution, I'm sure you can find more efficient ways to calculate how much stock was used up to `N` than simply running through all of the numbers one by one and looking at their decimal representation one by one.

Comment: Think about this.  How any 1s got used up for all of the numbers up to 256?  Well, you used it in the one's digit 25 times, in the ten's digit 30 times, and in the hundreds digit 100 times for 155.  Can you generalize?

Comment: Yes, I understand that I should do as much myself as possible. I simply meant my english was't good enough to get what you said :) I have found a simple pattern: 0-9: 1, 0-99: 20, 0-999: 300 etc.. I'll try to use it

Comment: I have found an efficient function to find the cost of numbers 1...n. I will edit the original post after I've implemented the trivial binary search later today. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate the answer directly. A recursive formula can determine how much stock is needed to get from `1` to numbers that are powers of ten minus 1:

```
f(n, power, target){
  if (power == target)
    return 10 * n + power;
  else
    return f(10 * n + power, power * 10, target);
}

f(0,1,1) = 1 // a stock of 1 is needed for the numbers from 1 to 9
f(0,1,10) = 20 // a stock of 20 is needed for the numbers from 1 to 99
f(0,1,100) = 300 // a stock of 300 is needed for the numbers from 1 to 999
f(0,1,1000) = 4000 // a stock of 4000 is needed for the numbers from 1 to 9999
```

Where it gets complicated is accounting for the extra `1`'s needed when our calculation lands after the first multiple of any of the above coefficients; for example, on the second multiple of 10 (11-19) we need an extra `1` for each number.

JavaScript code:

```
function f(stock){
  var cs = [0];
  var p = 1;
  function makeCoefficients(n,i){
    n  = 10*n + p;
    if (n > stock){
      return;
    } else {
      cs.push(n);
      p *= 10;
      makeCoefficients(n,i*10);
    }
  }

  makeCoefficients(0,1);
  var result = -1;
  var numSndMul = 0;
  var c;

  while (stock > 0){
    if (cs.length == 0){
      return result;
    }
    c = cs.pop();
    var mul = c + p * numSndMul;

    if (stock >= mul){
      stock -= mul;
      result += p;
      numSndMul++;
      if (stock == 0){
        return result;
      }
    }

    var sndMul = c + p * numSndMul;

    if (stock >= sndMul){
      stock -= sndMul;
      result += p;
      numSndMul--;
      if (stock == 0){
        return result;
      }
      var numMul = Math.floor(stock / mul);
      stock -= numMul * mul;
      result += numMul * p;
    }
    p = Math.floor(p/10);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Output:

```
console.log(f(600));
1180

console.log(f(17654321));
16031415

console.log(f(2147483647));
1633388154
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However I had already come up with a solution on my own. See the edit :)

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Thank you for your comment - you showed me another, more straightforward, way to calculate the stock needed for numbers that are powers of ten minus 1. Although practically not a big difference, I believe the complexity of my solution is `O(d)` where `d` is the number of (base 10) digits of the stock; whereas I think yours would be a log factor greater.

Comment: That is most likely so. Yours is definitely a bit more efficient, so good job on that. I think the fact that I'm unable to calculate the correct answer for numbers that have digits 1 and 0 in them without a for loop is my version's bottleneck. I believe my implementation is possible to optimize to work without the inner loop. Just can't come up with a solution out of the blue :) Good job on your solution nevertheless!